# How to prompt user input when GO application is in a pipeline

Tags: go, command-line, pipeline

My GO application needs to receive it's input from a pipeline and at the same time must prompt the user for the password.
Because I don't like set the password in a command parameter, I would like implement it exactly like `sudo` command does.

If I try to read from the stdin I will receive last command output as password (obviously).
I have also tried to use this library https://github.com/howeyc/gopass but it reads only from stdin.

Is there a way to do that in GO?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a simple example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and that has nothing to do with go. When you pipe to a program, you're directing the stdout of one program to the stdin of that program *instead of* the tty (what stdin would normally be attached to). A program only gets one stdin, so you can't both receive input piped from the output of another program, *and* receive input from the user's tty.

Comment: However you could handle the second program execution in Go (with something like exec.Command(...)) and pipe its stdout to your go, while being still able to read from stdin

Comment: Yes, you can handle them separately, just not using shell pipes.

Comment: Try to run this command `echo 'From pipeline' | sudo cat`. 
The echo output will be send to sudo input and sudo will prompt you for the password; then the piped input will be printed